# (How) can I use an array of strings as identifiers in C++?

Tags: c++, string, c-preprocessor, identifier

I'm working on this project where I need to parse a text file that contains a two-column table consisting of names on the left and values on the right.

Now, I need to write those to specific places in a control table, which are identified using hexadecimal addresses; in a header file that I can't edit, they have been defined as such:

```
#define HARRY_POTTER 0x3A
```

There's then a writing function that takes an address and a value and writes it into a storage place (this function is also out of my control). So, calling this

```
write(0x3A, 7);
```

Would have the same result as calling this

```
write(HARRY_POTTER, 7);
```

Because of that definition in the header file.

Now, I've got the parsing down, which basically gives me the left column, the name, as a string (so, "HARRY_POTTER", for example), and the right column, the value, as an integer.

What I'm wondering is if there's any way to use this string, "HARRY_POTTER" as the identifier in the write function; essentially converting the string into an identifier, so that I could just loop through my entire array of parsed values and it would automatically write them to the address that matches the string/ the name in the left column.

Is this possible? If yes, how?

Comment: Have you been introduced to `std::map`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not possible as you ask. The reason is because the string that you read from the file is only known at run-time, while preprocessing occurs at compile-time, so `HARRY_POTTER` must already have been replaced. In fact, no identifiers at all exist after the program has been compiled.

What you may want it to introduce a mapping from `std::string`s to the constants that you have defined. For example:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, int> mapping = {{"HARRY_POTTER", HARRY_POTTER},
                                                {"RON_WEASLEY", RON_WEASLEY}};
```

The constants will be replaced at compile-time, of course, so this is just equivalent to:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, int> mapping = {{"HARRY_POTTER", 0x3A},
                                                {"RON_WEASLEY", 0x7C}};
```

Then you can call `write` with:

```
write(mapping.at(key), 7);
```

Where `key` is a string with a value like `"HARRY_POTTER"`.

Comment: the call to write should check for the existence of the key first.  If it doesn't exist then it should either throw and exception or return an error code (although this code will actually already throw a std::out_of_range exception).

Comment: Ah, that makes sense! Thanks a lot, I'll use the unordered map you mentioned. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

(This answer fits way better in a comment, but I am still working up the reputation...)

I agree with Joseph that the way to go is an std::unordered_map in C++11 or a std::map in C++03.

I only wanted to add that you can make the code much more maintainable and easier to write by a bit of macro-magic in this case.

```
/* The stringify macro converts x to "x" at compile-time. */
#define _stringify(x) # x
#define stringify(x) _stringify(x)

/* Macro easing the assignment of { "String", value } */
#define STR_VAL(x) { stringify(x), (x) }

/* Now you can write the assignment code as follows */
std::unordered_map<std::string, int> mapping = {
    STR_VAL(HARRY_POTTER),
    STR_VAL(RON_WEASLEY),                                                          
    STR_VAL(ALBUS_BRIAN_WULFRIC_PERCIVAL_DUMBLEDORE)
};
```

This means that if the value of `#define HARRY_POTTER` ever changes your mapping code will be automatically updated when you recompile.